# About UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python

I am writing a program to count the words with python(3.6), the code runs smoothly from the terminal. But if I use python IDLE, below error happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/zhangchaont/python/Course Python Programming/6.7V2.py", line 122, in <module>
    main()
File "/Users/zhangchaont/python/Course Python Programming/6.7V2.py", line 21, in main
    for line in txtFile:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 33: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Please a a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not much info about your code. I can only suggest instead of codecs you can also use this package.
https://github.com/iki/unidecode. The method below should solve your problem. Open your file with `open` method, and pass it the `file_handle.read()`

```
unidecode.unidecode_expect_nonascii(string)
```